Sci-fi movie in which life expectancy of a child is determined at birth
The only scene I remember from this movie is that a woman gives birth to a child in a somewhat futuristic looking hospital. Once the baby is out a nurse holds a small hand-held device up to the baby, she then states the age at which the baby will die and the cause of death. This seems to be a standard procedure. The baby is then handed to the mother so she can embrace it, she seemingly doesn't care at this moment in time.
I can't remember the cause of death, so I'm not sure if the device saw a specific event in the future or if it detected a latent disease of some sort.

I've added a clip of the scene in question to Fruitbat's answer.

That sounds a bit like Gattaca (1997)
imdb
wiki
The story concerns a possible future where genetic manipulation is used to eliminate genetic disorders. People born without such manipulation are barred from certain jobs. 
There was a scene like you describe near the beginning of the film. There is a still of the nurse using the hand-held device on this blog
Youtube clip of the scene:



You're likely spot on, but could you provide a synopsis of the movie, specifically one that refferences the description the asker has provided? That'll make your answer more well rounded and useful than a couple of links.

@MattD - Patience young man! I've only just posted the answer. There's already been one over-zealous editor who managed to deleted half my answer within seconds of me answering. What I'm trying to find is a still from the scene described in the question.

Thanks for that. I've never actually heard of this movie prior to now, I must have caught some of it while flicking through TV years ago. Link to the trailer, the scene in the trailer only lasts a couple of seconds. The impression I get from the comments though is that the trailer doesn't really do the movie justice.

@Fruitbat: Youtube is often a good source. There are movie clips aplenty there, and if the scene was important/memorable/funny/intense/whatever enough, there's a good chance it will be there. I took the liberty of adding the clip I found to your answer.

Such a great under-appreciated movie.

@TrishLing Unless the film's copyright owner is being diligent in removing infringements from YouTube.
